# Can someone describe in detail (or in as much detail as possible) what neutrino physicists do?

Tags: nuclear-physics, soft-question, neutrinos

I'm a first-year graduate student; due to a series of unfortunate events I will most likely begin research in the spring (meaning I'll officially join a group and be on track for a research assistantship (RA)). This is a good thing. My choices have come down to neutrino physics (DUNE, NOvA, etc) and nuclear physics (studying fundamental problems in nuclear physics using spin properties of elementary particles).

I'm leaning toward neutrino physics because it seems to be an area of physics that could blossom in the next decade or two, and I have *some* amateur experience in the area as an undergrad, but this was mostly coding (which I enjoyed very much).

What exactly do neutrino physicists do? How much coding is involved? I plan on having a zoom call with some of the professors I want to work with, but I thought I would ask on here before doing so.

What do physicists who work on DUNE do during their time in the lab? What do those who work on NOvA do during their time in the lab? What do nuclear physicists do in the lab?

Comment: You can join snowmass community to learn more about it. I advise you to look into the career options (career options such as postdoc chances, faculty positions, national labs and so on) in each field and decide base on that. Do not decide based on interest if both of the look viable options.

Comment: Well, they try to gain evidence and information on neutrinos. This is especially hard as neutrinos do not act well with matter that we can control. It's been not so long ago that neutrinos were not known to have a rest mass and without, would be traveling at the speed of light. It is a really interesting field of research. Might be, a good part of dark matter is composed of neutrinos.

Comment: Those two choices aren't mutually exclusive when it comes to neutrino physics, in fact the nuclear community is very much interested in neutrino physics because neutrino scattering off nuclei is the dominant form of neutrino detection. So if neutrino physics interests you (I myself am in neutrino physics, working with fermilab to hopefully enhance their event generator), you can consider both those choices as important to the field overall

Comment: @KianMaleki From my understanding, the neutrino field is an area of physics that is likely to blossom in the next decade or two. Am I correct about this? I'll ask around just to be sure, but this is what I have heard in the past. I joined the snowmass young scientist mailing list but I could not create an account; I think there is something wrong with the CAPTCHA check on their website. I will email them for support soon.

Comment: @Triatticus Could you talk a little about your daily routine in this field? How often do you code? The little "in-lab" experience I have had has dealt mostly with coding (and some building), though this was for cosmology research, not pure neutrino research.

Comment: Coding is ubiquitous in all of physics at this point, but I don't have to do as much because I'm using my advisors MC generator she wrote to do her work. Primarily I use mathematics to determine matrix elements for each scattering process. Unfortunately her code is in Fortran as that allowed me to get the most help from her. Had I chosen to use C++ which would have also been a good choice....I'd be stuck rewriting her entire code from scratch.